# How to get Remote BLOB Storage for share point server 2010

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010

I have been asked to get Remote BLOB Storage into a SharePoint server. As per my research it's an add on feature for SQL Server 2008 r2.

Some installation process to be done http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631%28office.14%29.aspx.

I want to know am I on right path or its something simple to be done in SharePoint?

Comment: What do you want to know that is not already included in the instructions? They describe exactly how to install and configure RBS, so I don't know what extra information you need. I suggest you simply follow the instructions, and if you have problems then ask for help about whatever specific points are giving you difficulties.

Comment: ok so I have to enable in sql server and follow steps as in article.Thats exactly I wanted to know.